# Can you solve this problem with functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

We are given $f(x)=ax^2+2x+b$, a is not $0$, $Df=R$  and $f\circ g=g\circ f$ where $g(x)=x$ has only solution $x_0$. Then we have to show that $ab\leq 1/4$.

Comment: What is Df, Dg, R...? What have you tried, what have you done?

Comment: You should enclose math expressions in dollar signs for them to render properly. If $g(x)=x$ then of course $g\circ f=f\circ g$. What do you mean by $Dg$?

Comment: Ok so maybe in Greece we have other symbolisms..:/ Dg is where the function is defined.. So as it is defined in R it can take all the values for x.. Same with Df.. Sorry for the misunderstanding..

Comment: Domain of the function is $\Bbb R$... What else could it mean? But, @Nick, please check if you have copied the correct function for $g$. And which one has only solution $x_0$?

Comment: I have.. $g(x)=x$ and only $g(x)=x$ has the solution Xo

Comment: For $g(x)=x$ we have $f\circ g=g\circ f$ for all functions $f$, so that's not a condition.

Comment: I thought that as Xo is a solution for g(x) then $g(Xo) =0$ and i tried to replace this in the equation $fog=gof$ but i couldn't prove that $ab<=1/4$

Comment: Ok. So.. we don't have $g(x)=x$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. And.. $x_0$ is the zero of $g$ and not of $f$. Or what??

Comment: I think he means $g(x)=x$ has unique solution.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean... I will explain it again...  $g(x)=x$ has a unique solution Xo. So for X=Xo then $g(Xo)=0$ right?

Comment: No. For $x=x_0$ we have $g(x_0)=x_0$. $\quad$ I guess, some *continuity* of $g$ or something is also assumed.

Comment: But we are given that Xo is a solution for $g(x)$ ...:/ I really think that it means that $g(Xo)=0$ anyways...

Comment: It seems to be about the equation $f(x)=x$.

Comment: No. I think I got it: $x_0$ is a solution for the *equation* $g(x)=x$. And $g$ doesn't need to be polynomial, neither continuous, just a function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_0$ is a solution for $g(x)=x$, then we also have
$$g(f(x_0))=f(g(x_0))=f(x_0)$$
so $f(x_0)$ is *also* a solution of $g(x)=x$.

By uniqueness, we have $x_0=f(x_0)$, i.e.,
$$x_0=ax_0^2+2x_0+b\\ 
0=ax_0^2+x_0+b\,.$$
And, as $x_0$ is already a root of this polynomial $ax^2+x+b$, it must have nonnegative discriminant.

Comment: Yes that's what I also find.. And I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong...:/

Comment: you are not given that $f(x)$ has only one solution. You are given that $g(x)$ has only one solution. Which is Xo

Comment: I could take a picture of the exercise but except of the symbolisms everythin is written in greek..:/

Comment: Updated. I got it.

Comment: Ok yeah this is correct... But how do we prove that $ab<=1/4$?